# How to continue after sending GitHub pull request

Tags: github, pull-request, git-fork

I recently forked a project on GitHub to apply a fix, which I made on a fix-branch based off `upstream/master`'s head. Then I sent a pull request (that would ff-merge cleanly) which has been sitting around now for some time as the original repo hasn't really moved ever since.

Now I'd like to implement additional features on my fork using feature branches, but I'll of course want to base them on my fixed version without having to wait for the pull request to make its way into `upstream` (which for all I know might never happen at all). Furthermore, I'd like to maintain a public branch integrating all my fixes and changes.

How do people usually handle such a situation? I could, for instance, just merge the different fixes and feature branches into my fork's public `master` for integration, but expect that to get me in trouble in case `upstream` does move ahead and I'd like to pull its updates..?

Comment: Don't give up the hope. I had pull requests sitting for more than 6 months (and the whole repo appeared to be dead). Then, suddenly my PR was merged without further comment. Things might take time with some maintainers ;)

Comment: You could create your own `master2` branch based on the prelimiary merge of your PR and set it as the default branch in your fork. Keep working on that and if the other repo merges your PR, you can try to rebase your features on that.